# How would I use an array to store process started in a runtime, then mass destroy() them in a for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, runtime, destroy

So for example:

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();` creates `Runtime rt`

`Process p1 = rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe");` creates `Process p1` on `Runtime rt`.

Then `p1.destroy();` will destroy `Process p1`.

My question is: If I have more than one `Process` (e.g. `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`), how do I `destroy()` them all at once, instead of having to destroy them one by one?

And for a list, how would I implement a list into my code? I have not yet worked with lists and arrays, although I have tried to learn how to use them, but I guess it's one of those things where being taught with an example is much easier...

If you can help me, I will be happy to provide a PasteBin link to show what I am trying to do.

Also, a `for-loop` to `destroy()` the processes has been mentioned to me, but how would I go about that with a `Process`?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
for (int i = 0; i < nProcesses; ++i) {
    Process p = rt.exec(. . .);
    processes.add(p);
}
// then later...
for (Process p : processes) {
    p.destroy();
}
```

That last loop is called an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with). It's more or less equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); ++i) {
    Process p = processes.get(i);
    p.destroy();
}
```

Comment: It tells me that "type list does not take parameters". What do I do?

Comment: @TeddHopp If I PasteBin the code, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @TeddHopp This one: `List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();`

Comment: @user2506658 - Make sure that you imported `java.util.List` (and not `java.awt.List`).

Comment: @TeddHopp Ok, that fixed it. But now how do I get the processes to be executed?

Comment: @user2506658 - Each process should start executing when you call `exec`. The `Process` object that's returned is for managing your app's interaction with the process.

Comment: Could you take a look at my code for me? It's not working the way I want it to.

Comment: @user2506658 - If you've progressed to where you have a new problem, just post it as a new question.